# Why can't I use a variable from a \foreach loop inside a calc library macro?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

## Question

Why can't I use the \foreach variable as a percentage in my calculations with the `calc` library of TikZ?

### Sample Code

In the following, I could replace the variable `\mypercentage` with an arbitrary percentage, and the code will work.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=8,minimum width=5cm] (polygon) {};
\foreach \mypercent in {0.1,0.2,..,1.0}
    \node[draw,circle] (rightside) at ($ (polygon.corner 7) !\mypercent! (polygon.corner 8) $) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Goal

I would like to easily add an arbitrary number of coordinates / connection points to a line. The point is to use these coordinates as anchors. In other words, given segment A-B, add an arbitrary number of coordinates to that segment.

Comment: You need 3 dots - not 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can, if you use the right syntax (you need *three* dots in `{0.1,0.2,...,1.0}`):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=8,minimum width=5cm] (polygon) {};
\foreach \mypercent in {0.1,0.2,...,1.0}
    \node[draw,circle] (rightside) 
    at ($ (polygon.corner 7)!\mypercent!(polygon.corner 8) $) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```